# Excel - Change a cells value to that of another, depending on another cells value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Wasn't sure how to word the question, but here I go ...

Basically I have a table like the one below (Book1):

```
------------------------------------------------------
| ID    |  COUNTRY CODE     | NAME                   |
------------------------------------------------------
|  1    |  GB               | United Kingdom         |
|  2    |  AU               | Australia              |
|  3    |  BE               | Belgium                |
------------------------------------------------------
```

And I also have a table like this (Book2):

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| Country Code |       City       | Country code ID   |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  GB          |    London        |                   |
|  GB          |    Doncaster     |                   |
|  AU          |    Bowen         |                   |
|  BE          |    Halle         |                   |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, the country code ID column is not yet filled out. Is there a formula I can use to auto fill this column, with the data from the first table?

I'm using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx).  You'll first need to swap the columns A and B in Book1.  VLOOKUP will lookup a value in the first column in a range and return the corresponding value in another column.

The equation in Book2 C1 should be `=VLOOKUP(A1,Book1!$A$1:$B$3,2,FALSE)`

Then you simply copy the formula in C1 to the rest of the cells in the column and Excel will update the cell in the first part of the formula to the appropriate value.

Comment: Erm ... I forgot to mention I have 143000 cities to do this for ... I was hoping for a formula that would fill the entire cloumn ... And expanding the formula cell down the column doesnt work with this formula

Comment: Updated to reflect what happens when you copy the formula to the rest of the column... basically, Excel updates the cell reference for you.

Comment: Wait, got it! I used (Whilst in Book2, and columns changed like you said) `=VLOOKUP(A:A,[Book1]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)`